# Getting statistics on traffic sources for website usage

Tags: statistics, usage-data

Does anyone know a valid source where to get global statistics on how users access a webpage?

E.g.,

```
Site Referrer - 48%
Search Engines - 41%
Direct Entry - 1%
```

Comment: Are you asking about one particular site, or across all sites on the internet?

Answer (score 1):

I think Google Analytics would do this.